# Trying to achieve same functionality for auto-height divs under Chrome vs FF/IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have noticed a discrepancy between the heights of my divs in Chrome (which looks good) vs FireFox/IE.

Here's my HTML markup (I removed all the other tabs from this just to keep the code clean):

```
<div id="RightPane">
    <div id="RightPaneContent">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-6">Plan View</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-6">
            <%= Html.Partial("PlanViewTab", Model) %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#RightPaneContent
{
    min-width: 433px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here's how it looks under Google Chrome. Note how RightPaneContent expands to fill the entire height of viewport.

[image]

Here is how it looks under FireFox. Note how RightPaneContent did not expand to fill the entire viewport:

[image]

Does anyone have any advice on what steps I should take to achieve similiar functionality under both environments? Or at least some reading material on what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per CSS spec, `height: 100%` means the same thing as `height: auto` if the parent is auto-height.  Does your `<div id="RightPane">` have a height specified?  If not, chances are your page is in quirks mode, and WebKit just violates the standard slightly more in that mode than Gecko does.

Comment: You're correct. RightPane does not have a height specified, either. I wonder how I can achieve the functionality I am seeing in 'violated standards mode' in my other browsers, hmm.

Comment: Most simply, by making it work in standards mode in all browsers. ;)  For a start, set `height: 100%` on your RightPane?